# "Riagganciare" versus "riattaccare" (per il ricevitore del telefono)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

Ho trovato nel [dizionario](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/riagganciare) questa definizione per il verbo ***riagganciare***:

> Appoggiare il ricevitore del telefono interrompendo la comunicazione.

Comunque, nei romanzi di Andrea Camilleri appaiono molte telefonate ed è sempre il verbo ***riattaccare*** quello che viene usato. Ad esempio:

> «Catarella riattaccò, Montalbano macari e principiò a tornari in càmmara di letto. A mezza strata si fermò, santianno. Ma che minchia di telefonata era? Catarella lo chiamava alle sett’albe solo per vidiri se il sò ralogio caminava giusto? In quel momento il telefono sonò nuovamente, il commissario fu lesto a isare la cornetta al primo squillo.» (Andrea Camilleri, *La pazienza del ragno*)

Mi piacerebbe sapere se ci sono differenze regionali o di registro nell'uso dei verbi "riagganciare" e "riattaccare" per indicare la conclusione di una telefonata "appoggiando" il ricevitore.

Comment: *Riagganciare* è più formale.

Comment: Concordo con @egreg: nel parlato uso senza distinzione _riattacare_, _riagganciare_ e _chiudere_, ma scriverei solo _riagganciare_ o, al massimo, _chiudere_.

Comment: @gioele: Dunque, se ho capito bene, "riattaccare" è un termine che si usa nel parlato e non in un registro scritto formale. Questo concorda con lo stile intenzionalmente colloquiale che, a mio parere, Camilleri vuol dare al testo citato per esprimere le parole che in quel momento passano per la testa di Montalbano.

Comment: @gioele: Se è così, potresti scriverlo in una risposta?

Comment: oltre a _riattaccare_ si usa anche _attaccare_. Esiste anche _attaccare il telefono in faccia_ (o _chiudere il telefono in faccia_), col significato di "attaccare senza preavviso, solitamente mentre l'altro sta parlando"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personalmente, nel parlato uso senza distinzione sia *riattaccare* che *riagganciare* e *chiudere*.

Parlando di qualcuno che ha interrotto una comunicazione al telefono potrei dire senza problemi

> - Boh, *ha riattaccato.*
> - Boh, *ha riagganciato.*
> - Boh, *ha chiuso.*

Nello scritto, ad esempio raccontando quest'evento ad un conoscente, non avrei problemi a dire

> Poi, ad un certo punto, *ha riagganciato*.

Mi sembrerebbe troppo "confidenziale" scrivere

> Poi, ad un certo punto, *ha riattaccato*.

però lo potrei scrivere se volessi dare l'impressione di "scrivere come mangio".

Non userei invece

> Poi, ad un certo punto, *ha chiuso*.

O meglio, lo userei solo se il contesto fosse ben chiaro e l'azione di cui si sta parlando (chiudere il telefono/la telefonata) ovvia. Il verbo *chiudere* si usa per moltissime cose e *chiudere il telefono* o *chiudere la conversazione* non sono proprio le prime azioni che quel verbo richiama alla mente.

Answer (score 1):

Quando il ricevitore del telefono era la cornetta erano comuni entrambi, ora che di cornette non ce ne sono quasi più si dice 'chiudere'.

Sì, dubito esistano italiani con meno di vent'anni — cioè italiani che non hanno conosciuto la cornetta — che conoscano il significato 'telefonico' di quelle parole.

In più, il testo stralciato nella domanda (*Catarella riattaccò, Montalbano macari e principiò a tornari in càmmara di letto. […]*) non puo dirsi scritto in lingua italiana, peraltro.

Answer (score 1):

Molti anni fa si poteva soltanto "riagganciare", perché il ricevitore (molto simile a quello che usiamo oggi, quindi dopo l'uso della cornetta, che non ho mai avuto il piacere di usare) veniva davvero appoggiato su una specie di gancio metallico, sulla destra del telefono a muro che si abbassava e così chiudeva la conversazione. Un po' come nei più recenti telefoni pubblici. "Riagganciare" è quindi semplicemente più classico, ma oggi è come dire "riattaccare" o "chiudere".